# ссылки в цикле for

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, c++11, ссылки

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему когда мы перебирают элементы из какого то массива таким циклом for
`for(int& i : arr)`, то используют ссылку, а если перебирают символы в строке `for(char c : str)`, то ссылку не используют? Ведь и там, и там массив, и, чтобы не расходовать много памяти, разумнее и там, и там использовать ссылку. В чем различие? Заранее спасибо

Comment: ссылка нужна если собираемся модифицировать элементы контейнера. Либо когда эти элементы "тяжело" копировать(но тогда лучше использовать константную ссылку)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну почему же?

```
for(int i : arr)
```

работает не только не хуже, но и, пожалуй, лучше - не требуется никаких разыменований etc.

Можно работать и так, и так. Работа со ссылкой означает, что где-то там за сценой получается адрес очередного элемента, и при работе с этим элементом выполняется разыменование. По значению - что выполняется копирование.

А потому надо смотреть, что именно вам нужно - например, если вы хотите изменять элементы *в массиве*, то нужно работать по ссылке. Если, наоборот, вы хотите изменять содержимое переменной цикла, но при этом хотите, чтобы это не отразилось на исходном контейнере - работайте по значению. Если ситуация допускает и тот, и иной вариант - ст*о*ит посмотреть, какая операция - разыменования (возможно, не одна) или копирования - обойдется дороже. Для простых типов небольшого размера копирование, как правило, дешевле. Но вообще говоря - тут надо даже не смотреть на конкретный код, а *профилировать* его - если, конечно, оно того ст*о*ит с точки зрения оптимизации.

И не забывайте, что можно использовать еще и константную ссылку :)

Comment: Такой ответ  должен быть вполне достаточным, и его я принял бы...